# Find bounded solutions of second order ODE system

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Resulting from a Classical Mechanics problem, I have the following system of second order ODEs

$$
\begin{align}
\ddot{x} &= \frac{-kx}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \\
\ddot{y} &= \frac{-ky}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}
$$

With $k>0$ a real constant. I want to find the initial conditions for which the solutions of the system are bounded, and the initial conditions for which the system passes through the origin.

I know the origin is an unstable equilibrium point of the system, but I have no idea how to continue from there. I guess converting into polar coordinates would help with it, but I have only seen examples of converting systems of first order equations, not second order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Calling $p = (x(t),y(t))$ and also

$\cases{
T = \frac 12 ||\dot p||^2\\
U = -\frac{k}{||p||}}
$

we have the lagrangian

$$
L = T - U = \frac 12 ||\dot p||^2+\frac{k}{||p||}
$$

with the movement equations

$$
\cases{
\ddot x(t) = -\frac{k x(t)}{\left(x(t)^2+y(t)^2\right)^{3/2}}\\
\ddot y(t) = -\frac{k y(t)}{\left(x(t)^2+y(t)^2\right)^{3/2}}}
$$

The total energy is given by

$$
E = T + U = \frac 12 ||\dot p||^2-\frac{k}{||p||}
$$

NOTE

Making a change of coordinates

$$
\cases{
x(t) = r(t)\cos(\theta(t))\\
y(t) = r(t)\sin(\theta(t))
}
$$

on the former lagrangian we arrive at

$$
L = \frac{1}{2} \left(r'(t)^2+r(t)^2 \theta '(t)^2-\frac{2 k}{r(t)}\right)
$$

and now deriving the movement equations we arrive at

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
r''(t) = r(t) \theta '(t)^2-\frac{k}{r(t)^2} \\
 2 r(t)r'(t) \theta '(t)+r(t)^2 \theta ''(t)= (r(t)^2\theta'(t))' = 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

so we have

$$
r(t)^2\theta'(t) = h_0
$$

and substituting into the first movement equation we get

$$
r''(t) = \frac{h_0^2}{r(t)^3}-\frac{k}{r(t)^2} 
$$

etc.

Comment: I can't integrate the $E$ equation to know $\dot{p}$ because of the norm, so I should do a change of coordinates?

Comment: For a given set of initial conditions, $E$ is constant all along the trajectory. For instance, for $p_0 = (x_0, y_0)$ and $\dot p_0 = (v_{x_0}, v_{y_0})$ we have $E_0 = \frac 12(v_{x_0}^2+ v_{y_0}^2)-\frac{k}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}}$

Comment: so, going with the energetic argument, for certain values of the energy the trajectory will be bounded and for other it will not.

Comment: Please. Have a look at https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec16.pdf